# Restangular method being executed twice for 1 call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

I'm Angularjs novice and Restangular noob.
Here is my problem :

On my main controller I have this:

```
angular.module('examplesiteApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope,$location,Restangular) {

    Restangular.setBaseUrl('http://api.example.com/api/v1/');
    var baseAccounts = Restangular.all('auth/register/');
    console.log(baseAccounts);
```

at this command I get two elements (the same) logged in my console.

I have read a similar question and it says that using `ng-controller` with `$routeProvider` that causes the problem.

Here is my app.js

```
.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider,uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider) {
    uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure({
        key: 'secret_shit_or_not',
        v: '3.17',
        libraries: 'geometry,visualization,places'
    });
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/home/slider.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
```

The template looks like :

```
<body ng-controller="GeneralCtrl">
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->
    <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
    <div ng-include src="'views/main.html'"></div>
    <div ng-view></div>
```

depending on the url ng-view gets a defined value (dynamic process).
The GeneralController is a simple controller:

```
angular.module('peersiteApp')
  .controller('GeneralCtrl', function ($scope , $location) {
    $scope.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];
    $scope.isAt = function(route){
      return route === $location.path();
    };
  });
```

Can you tell me why I'm having Restangular firing twice ? Help the Angular John snow which I am.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution :

I was calling ng-controller inside a sub view.